# Selecting features on PostGIS table from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, features, tools

I use **QGIS 2.14.11-Essen** and **PostGIS 2.1.8**. This is an issue I had not with previous QGIS versions. I work with LTR version for my work so upgrade to current version (2.18.3) is not possible for now.

Selecting features tools work perfectly with shapefiles but not with tables loaded from a PostGIS database *via* DB Manager. Clicking on a feature (or englobing it with a selection rectangle) does not select it either visually or within attributes table. The only workaround I found is to select a feature from the attributes table (select a row) and therefore, the feature is coloring on the map canvas...

I checked [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/182223/22693) which is not exactly the same issue (shapefiles) but the solutions didn't help me.

Eventually, I can't see any errors when I load the table or within DB Manager UI:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found out that this was because I added the PostGIS Layer using the "Add Vector Layer" button. When I added the PostGIS Layer using the "Add PostGIS Layer" button I was able to select features in this layer.

Comment: Thanks @georg! I usually prefer using DB Manager to add a PostGIS table because displaying the content of a big database is much faster. I've just tried again with *Add PostGIS Layer* menu and it takes quite a long to display all the schemas...